# Force iptables to immediately put drop rule into effect

Tags: iptables, iptables-persistent

I have the following setup: in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Jul  1 11:32:00 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:620]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.35.107/32 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 192.168.35.0/24 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.35.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jul  1 11:32:00 2019
```

from above we see that I want to block ping from specific IP.
After I save rules with `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4`, and I list rules with `iptables -L`, I can conclude that computer with ip 192.168.35.107 is unable to ping the server.

However, the computer with that IP is able to ping **indefinitely** until I break the session. Even after I break the ping I still need to make ~60 seconds pause until I am unable to ping again. If I make 5-10 seconds pause between ping command the firewall let me through.

Funnily enough when I enable ping through the iptables it works immediately.
I have tried with the Samba port 445 as well. Same.

Is there a way to make iptables dropped ports immidiately effective?

Comment: `-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` is to blame. This rule allows any established (running) connection as well as any related ones to run even if another rules prohibit. removing this line should give you desired result.

Comment: Well not remove, but move it below the DROP rules that should take priority, as explained in the answer below..

Comment: Works! that line is of course "Allow related and already established connections"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're experiencing that behavior because your system has the netfilter's connection tracking system (the `nf_conntrack*` family of modules) enabled *and* your `--state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule (obviously set to `ACCEPT`) is placed before the ping's specific `DROP` rule.

The `-m state` rules, as well as the more fine-grained `-m conntrack` rules, rely on the connection-tracking system which also tracks protocols such as UDP and ICMP even though these are technically not connection-oriented. It tracks those protocols by building a "connection" entry in its list with a default expiry timeout. These default values can be queried and set through the specific files under `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/`, typically those named `nf_conntrack_*_timeout`.

Being ICMP a connection-less protocol, the connection-tracking system has no way to detect when any such "connection" really has finished, and thus can only rely on a timeout-driven heuristic. Therefore, as long as there is an entry in the connection-tracking-list matching your source-ip/destination-ip icmp "conversation", any `-m state --state ESTABLISHED` rule will match that traffic, in your case ACCEPTing it as per your particular rule.

The "~60 seconds" timeout you notice should actually be 30 seconds as this is usually the default value for `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout`. However it may have been changed by just `echo`ing a different value into that file.

Note also that values in those files are for new "connections" from then on. To see current entries as known by the connection-tracking system, along with their current expiring timeout, you can use the `conntrack` command, which you may need to install. Using that command you can also modify or delete the entries.

> Is there a way to make iptables dropped ports immidiately effective?

The simplest way is to always place `DROP` rules before the `-m state` ACCEPT rule.

One alternative might be: each time you add a `DROP` rule, also run a respective `conntrack` command to delete currently active entries.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you still have an entry in the connection table for that host, and the `iptables` utility will not flush it or mess with it in any way when adding or removing its rules.

For that, you should install the [`conntrack(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/conntrack/conntrack.8.en.html) utility, which can be used to manipulate the kernel's live connection tracking table. It's using a netlink socket interface for that, which offers functionality not available via `/proc` or other means.

For example, `conntrack -F` will flush all connections, `conntrack -D --dst=8.8.8.8` will delete all entries with that destination, `conntrack -D --src=192.168.35.107` will delete all entries with that source, etc.

It's readily installable on most distros with eg. `apt-get install conntrack`, `yum install conntrack`, etc.